# rails 4: acts-as-taggable-on view object tags from parent / relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on in an app where I would ideally like to view the tags of a child record (has_many / belongs_to).

Parent Model

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :artifacts
end
```

Child Model

```
class Artifact < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  acts_as_taggable_on
  # ... other code
end
```

Obviously, I can list all the tags on a given artifact

```
@artifact.tags
```

What I would like to (easily) see is all the unique tags for every artifact in a project.

e.g.

Project called Lilies

-- has 3 artifacts

1. Rocks
2. Globes
3. Gems

The Gems artifact has 9 tags (red, blue, white, white-yellow, yellow, green, blue, haze, teal)

The Globes artifact has 2 tags (bounderies, laylines)

The Rocks artifact has 3 tags (limestone, sandstone, claystone)

So if I wanted to see all 14 tags for the whole project (cheaply) - can someone point me in the right direction.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag` to lists all the tags you have. If you want more details on which artifact the tags link to, you can go for `ActsAsTaggableOn::Tagging`.

Comment: I'm not sure how that helps me.  The taggable element isn't the one I'm searching for, it's the taggable element's parent.  Can you expound?

Comment: ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.all will give you a list of all your tags, or if you only want to select all tags name, you can do this `ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.all.pluck(:name)` which will result in `[red, blue, white, white-yellow, etc]`